# Transformation of Functions why and real life

Tags: graphing-functions

I know how to use transformations of functions. The question is why do we need to learn transformations of functions? Also, how do we use them in real life, so as a real life application.

Transformations such as graphing y =(x-2)^2 + 1 using the graph of y =x^2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a transformation of a function is like taking $f(x) = x^2$ as a base and then considering, for example $f(x) = ax^2 + c$. One example where this comes in handy to understand intuitively, that comes up in my job all the time, is in statistical modeling. Basically, when you want to fit a set of known data points to a function, it helps to understand how different transformations affect the output of the function, and how to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the graph can also be used "backwards" in the case of linear transformations, to keep the graph in place and shift/scale the axes, instead. For example (courtesy [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point#/media/File:Dewpoint-RH.svg)), this is what allows the following chart to display both Celsius (bottom/left) and Fahrenheit (top/right) degrees.

[image]